# Unable to insert elements in circular doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am unable to insert elements in this circular doubly linked list. First element gets entered without any issue. But as soon as I try to insert the second element, a problem is encountered. The problem is: program terminates itself.
I don't know exactly where I am going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
}list;

list *start=NULL;
list *end=NULL;

void insert();
void display();
void reverse_display();

void main()
{
  int n;

  printf("1: Insert Elements\n");
  printf("2: Display\n");
  printf("3: Reverse Display\n");

  for(;;)
  {
    printf("Enter choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    switch(n)
    {
      case 1: insert();
      break;

      case 2: display();
      break;

      case 3: reverse_display();
      break;

      default: printf("Wrong Input!!!\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}


void insert()
{
  int num;
  list *new_node , *ptr;

  printf("Enter the number: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  new_node = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  new_node->data = num;

  if(start == NULL)
  {
      new_node->next = start;
      new_node->prev = end;
      start = new_node;
      end = new_node;
  }
  else
  {
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr->next != start)
      ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = new_node;
    new_node->prev = ptr;
    new_node->next = start;
    start->prev = new_node;
    end = new_node;
  }
}

void display()
{
  list *ptr;
  ptr = start;
  printf("\nElements in original order:\n");
  if(start == NULL)
    printf("Empty List!!!\n");
  else
  {
    while(ptr->next!=start)
  {
    printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
  }
}

void reverse_display()
{
  list *ptr , *temp;
  ptr = end;
  printf("\nElements in reverse order\n");
  while(ptr->prev!=end)
  {
    printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->prev;
  }
  printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
}
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you immediately the exact line of code that triggers the program termination. You can also use it to step the code line by line and examine the program variables.

Comment: Your insertion logic is broken (I'm fairly confident it isn't the only problem, but its broken nonetheless). If start (and thus end) are NULL, the new node should be self referencing. (i.e. both next and prev should reference the node that contains them). Your logic sets both next and prev to start and end respectively *prior* to setting start and end to the new node. Therefore start and end now reference a node whos next and prev are both null. Therefore `while(ptr->next != start) ptr = ptr->next;` is guaranteed to deference a null pointer after the first step of iteration.

Comment: Also worth noting, your `reverse_display` will invoke undefined behavior if the list is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a doubly circular linked list, if there is one node then it's `next` and `prev` pointer should point to itself. In `insert()`, you are doing

```
  if(start == NULL)
  {
      new_node->next = start;
      new_node->prev = end;
     ......
```

due to this, the `next` and `prev` pointers end up pointing to `NULL` because `start` and `end` are initially set to `NULL`. Now, when you insert another element in the list, you are end up accessing `NULL` pointer

```
    while(ptr->next != start)
       ptr = ptr->next;
```

and that's why you are observing program termination.

When inserting first node, you should properly set the `next` and `prev` pointers. In your code, just set the `start` and `end` pointer before setting `next` and `rev`, like this:

```
  if(start == NULL)
  {
      start = new_node;
      end = new_node;
      new_node->next = start;
      new_node->prev = end;
  }
```

---

Additional:

- Using `void` as return type of `main` function is not as per standards. The return type of `main` function should be `int`.
- Follow good programming practice, always check the `malloc` return.
- Do not cast the `malloc` return.